# Computing the Cosine Similarity of Embeddings Generated by the Dolly Model on the Hugging Face Hub

Tags: python, numpy, huggingface-transformers, valueerror

In Python, I have a text query variable and a dataset structured as follows:

```
text = "hey how are you doing today love"
dataset = ["hey how are you doing today love", "I am doing great", "What about you?"]
```

I am trying to use the following pipeline to calculate the cosine similarity between the Dolly embeddings of text and dataset as follows:

```
# Import Pipeline

from transformers import pipeline
import torch
import accelerate
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize


# Create Feature Extraction Object

feature_extraction = pipeline('feature-extraction',
                              model='databricks/dolly-v2-3b', 
                              torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
                              trust_remote_code=True, 
                              device_map="auto")


# Define Inputs

text = ["hey how are you doing today love"]
dataset = ["hey how are you doing today love", "I am doing great", "What about you?"]

# Create Embeddings

text_embeddings = feature_extraction(text)[0]
dataset_embeddings = feature_extraction(dataset)

text_embeddings = np.array(text_embeddings)
dataset_embeddings = np.array(dataset_embeddings)

text_embeddings = normalize(text_embeddings, norm='l2')
dataset_embeddings = normalize(dataset_embeddings, norm='l2')

cosine_similarity = np.dot(text_embeddings, dataset_embeddings.T)
angular_distance = np.arccos(cosine_similarity) / np.pi
```

The L2 normalization is failing, and if I "comment it out" I am running into the following error:

```
ValueError: shapes (1,7,2560) and (1,3) not aligned: 2560 (dim 2) != 1 (dim 0)
```

I know that the error has something to do with the misalignment of the shapes of text_embeddings and dataset_embeddings. However, I am not sure about what I can do to resolve it.

Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things happening here:

- `dolly-v2-3b` gives you multiple embeddings for a given text input, where the number of embeddings depends on the input you provide. For example, while the model provides 7 embeddings (also called vectors) for the first sentence in `dataset`, it provides 4 embeddings for the subsequent 2.
- `cosine similarity` measures the similarity between **two** vectors. The code you provided tries to compare multiple vectors of one sentence with multiple vectors of another sentence; which violates the aforementioned operation that `cosine similarity` performs. Therefore, before performing the similarity computations, we need to "condense" the embeddings into a single vector - the code below uses a technique called "vector averaging", which simply computes the average of the vectors.
- It's required to call `np.average` (which is used for vector averaging) and `np.normalize` for each sentence individually in `dataset`.

The code below runs without error and returns a `cosine similarity` of `1` for the first comparison where we compare the sentence to itself, which is expected. Moreover, the undefined `np.NaN` angular difference between the two identical vectors of the first comparison also makes sense.

```
# Installations required in Google Colab
# %pip install transformers
# %pip install torch
# %pip install accelerate

from transformers import pipeline
import torch
import accelerate
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize


# Create Feature Extraction Object

feature_extraction = pipeline('feature-extraction',
                              model='databricks/dolly-v2-3b', 
                              torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
                              trust_remote_code=True, 
                              device_map="auto")


# Define Inputs

text = ["hey how are you doing today love"]
dataset = ["hey how are you doing today love", "I am doing great", "What about you?"]

# Create Embeddings
text_embeddings = feature_extraction(text)
dataset_embeddings = feature_extraction(dataset)

# Perform Vector Averaging
text_embeddings_avg = np.average(text_embeddings[0], axis=1)
dataset_embeddings_avg = np.array(
    [
        np.average(text_embedding, axis=1)
        for text_embedding
        in dataset_embeddings
    ]
)
print(text_embeddings_avg.shape)  # (1, 2560)
print(dataset_embeddings_avg.shape)  # (3, 1, 2560)

# Perform Normalization
text_embeddings_avg_norm = normalize(text_embeddings_avg, norm='l2')
dataset_embeddings_avg_norm = np.array(
    [
        normalize(text_embedding, norm='l2')
        for text_embedding
        in dataset_embeddings_avg
     ]
)
print(text_embeddings_avg_norm.shape)  # (1, 2560)
print(dataset_embeddings_avg_norm.shape)  # (3, 1, 2560)

# Cosine Similarity
cosine_similarity = np.array(
    [
        np.dot(text_embeddings_avg_norm, text_embedding.T)
        for text_embedding
        in dataset_embeddings_avg_norm
    ]
)
angular_distance = np.arccos(cosine_similarity) / np.pi
print(cosine_similarity.tolist())  # [[[1.0000000000000007]], [[0.7818918337438344]], [[0.7921756683919716]]]
print(angular_distance.tolist())  # [[[nan]], [[0.21425490131377858]], [[0.2089483418862303]]]
```